# Rails, Alphabet range ('a'..'z') for non-English characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**('a'..'z')** and other range <strike>methods</strike> literals comes in very handy.

Is there an equivalent or some sort of other range method to display alphabets other than English? (*exempli gratia* German alphabet (umlaut characters), Turkish alphabet)

**UPDATE**
My use case is:
I am generating random strings from alphabets. So i need all the characters in the alphabet before randomizing and re-joining them at specified length. In English, I can do: `('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle[0, length].join.capitalize`. I want to do the same for other alphabets too.

Comment: That is not a method. It is a range literal.

Comment: Note that ordering of characters in Ruby is based on ASCII code. Even if you  consider extended ASCII code, umlaut characters are not adjacent to English alphabets, so I don't think it would be useful.

Comment: @sawa on `codepoints`, to be precise, not on ASCII. `('а'..'я')` works as well.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks for correcting. I do respect Russians.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won’t work that way. There is in fact no determined character for, say, “o umlaut.” Look:

```
▶ 'ö'.codepoints
#⇒ [
#  [0] 246
# ]
▶ 'ö'.codepoints
#⇒ [
#  [0] 111,
#  [1] 776
# ]
```

Cool, huh? The reason is that the former is a character that came from `ISO-8859-1` and the latter is “o” + [combining diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character). I would suggest to either use bindings to [icu library](http://site.icu-project.org/), or to try to handle everything manually (leading to buggy and insupported codebase.)

**UPD** As @NeilSlater pointed in his comment, once there are no, say, combining diacritics ever possible, one might write:

```
[*('a'..'z'), 'ö', 'ä', 'ü']
```

Comment: The answer could be different if the use case for the OP was explained. Separate diacritic characters may not be an issue if OP is *generating* content from a set of characters for example.

Comment: More precisely, both are utf-8, but the former is the NFC form of the character, and the latter is NFD form of ö.  But yes, the codepoint for the unicode character is the same as the latin-1 one.